# Enable systray icons in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, icons, system-tray

Does anyone know how to get systray icons working again in Ubuntu 16.04? (the app I have in mind is a 3rd party one, UpWork, but I guess this applies to many different apps that use old style sys tray icons, making the question more general).

So far I have tried installing

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

to no avail.

I also have read articles which suggest `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty`, but this is obviously not for xenial and appears not longer maintained anyway.

Is there anyway to regain systray icons for apps in xenial? (or I guess more specifically apps that don't have an AppIndicator and use the old notification area)

Comment: In `terminal` try `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity name_of_program` and see if the systray icon shows up. If it does, I'll give you a permanent fix. Ping me at `@heynnema`.

Comment: It didn't work sadly.

Comment: Eh, we tried. Sorry.